# TypeScript+AngularJs:- How to pass the parameters through ng-Change to typescript function

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript1.4, angularjs-ng-change, typescript1.5

I have implemented a module using TypeScript and Angular Js. I have populated a dropdown using ng-options where i m using ng-change too.Now i want to send index of selected value and that selected value to the function called on ng-change and set that value in to function too.so that i can send those values to my API Controller.
Here is my code for DropDown:-

```
<div data-ng-app="CustomerNew" data-ng-controller="CreateCustomerCtrl as custom" ng-init="getFormData();">
    <tr>
    <td>Billing Type:</td>
    <td>
    <select id="listBillingType" 
    ng-change="listBillingTypeselectedindexchange((index.Of(blngtypee),(custom.listBillingType))"data-ng-options="blngtype as blngtypee for (blngtype,blngtypee) in listBillingType" 
    data-ng-model="custom.listBillingType" 
    style="width: 182px !important; height: 34px;">
    <option value="">Choose an option {{optional ? '(optional)' : ''}}</option>
    </select>
    </td></tr>
</div>
```

Here is my typescript controller code:-

```
 public listBillingTypeselectedindexchange = (listBillingTypeselectedindexchange: any) => {
             debugger;
             var data = {
            index:here is want to set the value of my index
            selectedvalue:here i want to set the value of my selected value
             }
             this.$http.post(doAccountTypeUrl,data).
                 success((data, status, headers, config) => {
                 debugger;
             }).
                 error((data, status) => {
                 debugger;
                 console.log("In Error:-in index");
                 alert(status);
             });

         }
```

As you can see if i got both values so i m able to send the same to my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer we can Pass the parameters like as i shown below:-

```
<div data-ng-app="CustomerNew" data-ng-controller="CreateCustomerCtrl as custom" ng-init="getFormData();">
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Billing Type:</td>
<td>
<select id="listBillingType" ng- change="listBillingTypeselectedindexchange(custom.listBillingType)"
data-ng-options="blngtype as blngtypee for (blngtype,blngtypee) in listBillingType" 
data-ng-model="custom.listBillingType" style="width: 182px !important; height: 34px;">
<option value="">Choose an option {{optional ? '(optional)' : ''}}</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</div>
```

In My TypeScript Controller:-

```
 public listBillingTypeselectedindexchange = (Item) => {
         debugger;
         var data = {
             selecteditem: Item
         }
         this.$http.post(Url,data).
             success((data, status, headers, config) => {
         }).
             error((data, status) => {
             console.log("In Error");
             alert(status);
         });
```